# How to create a child object from another object with polymorphic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, clone

I have two classes, `Tutor` and `Session` which share the same child class `Field` in polymorphic relationship.

When a tutor create a session, I would like to have the title to be automatically copied from Tutor to Session (i.e., a new entry will be added to 'Field' table). For example,

```
t = Tutor
Session.fields.build_from_tutor(t.fields)
```

I just make up build_from_tutor method. Is there a Rails/Ruby way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same entries to exist as the children of two classes, that's not polymorphic; that's just confused inheritance. Either a `Tutor has_many :sessions`, and a `Session has_many :fields`, and thus a `Tutor has_many :fields, :through => :sessions`, or alternately, a `Tutor has_many Sessions, :as => :fieldable`, a `Session has_many :fields, :as :feildable`, and a `Field belongs_to :fieldable, :polymorphic => true`, but that would preclude Tutor and Session ever *sharing* a field.

So you need to figure that out. Then you can work out a sane builder. But yhe way you have it, you'll never be able to normalize your data model. Even for a Rails application, you should hold yourself to 3NF as a minimum standard, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks Jason. No, I don't want same entry for two classes. For each topic in Tutor, there's one record. For each topic in Session, there's another record. Topic has polymorphic relationship with Tutor AND Session.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused by the way the question was phrased; if Fields is truly polymorphic, and you just want the `title` attribute copied from `Tutor` to `Session` you could use callbacks, i.e., if `Tutor` should be created at the same time as `Session`, do: `class Tutor; after_save :make_session; def make_session; self.topic.build_session(:title => self.title);end;end` The problem with this approach is that you violate both 3NF and the DRY principle; you're duplicating information within the database. If you need `title` to exist in two records, you should revise your DB schema.